# Maven Dependencies or Eclipse Project Facet

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, servlets

I created a project in Eclipse (Oxygen) using maven with no archetype. My question is ... to use the Servlet API, if I use "Project Properties> Project Faces" and add "Dynamic Web Module", is it the same as adding the dependency in pom.xml of the Servlet API (javax. servlet-api)?

I mean...

*Project Properties > Project Facets > Dynamic Web Module 4.0 (Checked)*

Is the same as...?

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
  <version>4.0</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

[Project Facets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J4FHm.png)

[Maven Dependency](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BkCUT.png)

Comment: Did you try anything? What did you find when you added the facet?

Comment: I guess it doesn't do same thing, as I tried creating a project as you mentioned, and selected project facets, updated maven project but it hasn't added any servlet dependency to the pom. I think project facets are for runtime configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Project facets allows IDE to understand your project better so that it can perform some special operations for you. For example, applying Dynamic Web Module would make eclipse know that your Project would be running on Web Server, hence you would need that facet to add your project to a Web Server. As you apply Dynamic Web Module to your project, eclipse also assumes that you would be provided with web server dependencies in the run time. Facets stays at IDE level.

While maven dependency provides you with the libraries required in your project to perform your task. They stay with your project package when it is deployed.

Comment: "While maven dependency provides you with the libraries required in your project to perform your task. They stay with your project package when it is deployed." Unless you marked dependency as "provided", no?

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
 <dependency>
<groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
<artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
<version>4.0</version>
<scope>provided</scope>
```

Go to Project properties > Project facets > click on runtimes which is in right side of Project Facets > checked that server >Apply and close

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D9sbh.png)

Comment: Question is what is the difference between two.

Comment: In apache server package or Dynamic Web Module javax servlet-api jar is available if  you add it through project facets then that jar will add in your project and if we put dependency of javax servlet-api then also that jar will add in your project So both are same..

Comment: Looks like its not the same.Dynamic Web Module > Project Facets > Runtime > Runtime and select Apache Tomcat 9.0, this import all the tomcat libraries with specific versions, there is restriction in the versions. Maven Dependency, add the Servlet API with the version that i want.